# Should this question be classified as "why isn't this working" type question

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187662/java-lang-runtimeexception-com-android-builder-dexing-dexarchivemergerexception) quite literally boils down to "I did this <snippet>, but it gives error message <error message>".

Even though the snippet and error message is complete, I didn't see a question nor the OP's desired behaviour anywhere. My immediate conclusion is that the question fits precisely into the category of "why isn't this working" type questions.

I recommended deletion, but was informed that I failed the audit. Not being familiar with android, is this question acceptable?

Comment: If people disagree, tell me why the post was good and where my understanding is wrong. Otherwise, I'm either going to go on a bad close voting spree and get banned, or stop voting altogether, neither of which is helpful

Comment: If you are not familiar with the technology, skipping is perfectly alright.

Comment: Since "android" tag covers pretty much any language and framework you can find (as long as it can be used on android) guessing if question is actually makes sense or not is hard - skipping sounds like a good idea (unless you are frequent visitor for the tag, which you clearly are not)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Does this extend to other topics? I don't see how it makes sense for the review queue to **not** filter out everything I'm not familiar with otherwise.

Comment: @PasserBy I apply that only to "android" tag... normally for review you just see if questions align with SO quality guidelines, but I found that "android" tag has very "relaxed" bar and thus way too likely to be hit audit you guess review wrong...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I will keep that in mind. It is good to know I didn't misvote a billion posts in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question feels like one I'd skip.  Me not knowing Android makes me feel like I'd get this wrong more often than right.

I'd also like to call out

> My immediate conclusion is that the question fits precisely into the category of "why isn't this working" type questions.

A question can be *closed* as "why isn't this working" if it doesn't include basic information, like the code they're using, the error message they've gotten, and some way to execute the above for onlookers.  From an initial look, it *feels* like they satisfied these requirements already, so closing it wouldn't be an ideal fit.

Answer (score 1):

This question was just closed for being caused by an error that could no longer be reproduced, and all five of us agreed on that outcome. But, it should have potentially been edited before - the layout of the question made it difficult to find the relevant bits, and the comments contained useful additional information that should have been put into the question.

So, the answer ultimately is "no" - not the least reason of which is that there actually was no code presented (a gradle file is a configuration, not code).